# Hibernate: How to check whether the current thread has a session bound to it?

Tags: hibernate

Is there a failsafe, no-hacks -kind of way to check whether the current thread has a session bound to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a session object in the current thread then you can always use `session.isConnected()` method which you can use to find out if the session is active. If you would like to know if the transaction is turned on use `session.getTransaction().isActive()`.
If you are not sure if the session is open or not, you can always use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` method, if the session is already open then it will be returned or else a new one will be created for you.

Apart from this i'm not sure if there is a way to know if the session is bound to the thread.